# Is there a way to render a Django formset in Jinja2 using the batch filter to create a grid?

Tags: django, jinja2

I'm looking to render a Django formset similar to a spreadsheet with rows and columns.  I was hoping to use the Jinja2 filter "batch" to create the columns but I'm not sure if that is possible.

I know I can render the formset using for loops in Jinja but it's getting very messy as I've also got to add non-form information at points in the rendering and the position of that information is dynamic.

Ideally, I would like to set the column loop up with "batch", then apply another set of loops to render the actual column forms and non-form data, then repeat this for each column.

I appreciate any input or insights you may have.